# generate a 2d array of integers from given sums of its rows and columns

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I want to generate an array of integers where the total sum of each row and column in the array is known , for example if I create a 4 by 4 array in c++ and then populate it pseudo randomly with numbers between 1 and 100:

```
int array[4][4] = {} ;
for(int x = 0 ; x<4 ; x++){
   for(int y = 0 ; y<4 ; y++){
      array[x][y] = rand() % 100 + 1 ;
   }
}
```

the array would be :

```
 8, 50, 74, 59
31, 73, 45, 79
24, 10, 41, 66
93, 43, 88,  4
```

then if I sum each row and each column by :

```
int rowSum[4] = {} ; 
int columnSum[4] = {} ; 
for(int x = 0 ; x < 4; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 4; y++){
        rowSum[x] += array[x][y] ;
        columnSum[y] += array[x][y] ;
    }
}
```

the rowSum would be `{191,228,141,228}` and the columnSum = `{156,176,248,208}`

what I'm trying to do at this point is to generate any random 4x4 1~100 array that will satisfy `rowSum`  and `columnSum` I understand there is thousands of different arrays that will sum up to the same row and column sum ,and I've been trying to write the part of the code that will generate it , I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me a clue .

Comment: Heh heh. There are a lot more than a few thousand. I wrote a little brute force search, and very early in the search space it's found 3.5 _billion_ solutions.

Comment: @Gene The number of solutions is infinite (in practice bounded by the size of the integer).

Comment: @n.m. I'm inferring from his example that he wants non-negative exemplars.

Comment: @Gene Oh, then it's bounded obviously.

Comment: yeah I understand the power of exponential at play thats why it should be easier to write some algorithm instead of brute forcing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to find *some* solution.

Start with generating row that sum to given values. It could be as simple as making all values in each row approximately equal to `rowSum[i]/n`, give or take one. Of course sums of columns will not match at this point.

Now fix the columns from the leftmost to the rightmost. To fix *i* th column, distribute the difference between the desired sum and the actual sum equally between column entries, and then fix each row by distributing the added value equally between items `i+1...n` of the row.

It is easier done than said:

```
void reconstruct (int array[4][4], int rows[4], int cols[4])
{   
    // build an array with each row adding up to the correct row sum
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
        int s = rows[x]; 
        for(int y = 0; y < 4 ; y++){
            array[x][y] = s / (4 - y);
            s -= array[x][y];
        }
    }

    // adjust columns
    for(int y = 0; y < 4 ; y++){
        // calculate the adjustment
        int s = 0; 
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
            s += array[x][y];
        }
        int diff = s - cols[y];
        // adjust the column by diff
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
            int k = diff / (4 - x);
            array[x][y] -= k; 
            diff -= k;
            // adjust the row by k
            for (int yy = y + 1; yy < 4; ++yy)
            {   
                int corr = k / (4 - yy);
                array[x][yy] += corr;
                k -= corr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This array won't be random of course. One can randomise it by selecting x1, x2, y1, y2 and d at random and executing:

```
 array[x1][y1] += d
 array[x1][y2] -= d
 array[x2][y1] -= d
 array[x2][y2] += d
```

taking care that the resulting values won't spill out of the desired range.

Comment: thanks man ! I thought about dividing the sum by 4 for the row but I didn't know what to do about the columns

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick and dirty brute force search mentioned in comments. It ought to give you a starting point.  This is C, not C++.

You never said it, but I'm assuming you want the matrix elements to be non-negative. Consequently, this searches the space where each element a[i][j] can have any value in [0..min(rowsum[i], colsum[j])] with the search cut off when assigning the next array element value would admit no possible future solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[4][4] = {
  {-1, -1, -1, -1},
  {-1, -1, -1, -1},
  {-1, -1, -1, -1},
  {-1, -1, -1, -1}};
int rs[] = {191, 228, 141, 228};
int cs[] = {156, 176, 248, 208};
long long n_solutions = 0;

void research(int i, int j, int ii, int jj, int val);
void print_a(void);

void search(int i, int j) {
  if (j < 3) {
    if (i < 3) {
      int m = rs[i] < cs[j] ? rs[i] : cs[j];
      for (int val = 0; val <= m; ++val) research(i, j, i, j + 1, val);
    } else {
      if (rs[3] >= cs[j]) research(i, j, i, j + 1, cs[j]);
    }
  } else {
    if (i < 3) {
      if (cs[j] >= rs[i]) research(i, 3, i + 1, 0, rs[i]);
    } else {
      if (rs[3] == cs[3]) {
        a[3][3] = rs[i];
        if (++n_solutions % 100000000 == 0) {
          printf("\n%lld\n", n_solutions);
          print_a();
        }
        a[3][3] = -1;
      }
    }
  }
}

void research(int i, int j, int ii, int jj, int val) {
  a[i][j] = val; rs[i] -= val; cs[j] -= val;
  search(ii, jj);
  rs[i] += val; cs[j] += val; a[i][j] = -1;
}

void print_a(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
      printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  search(0, 0);
  printf("Total solutions: %lld\n", n_solutions);
  return 0;
}
```

For example, if you replace the simple `for` loop with this, you won't get so many zeros in the upper left hand corner:

```
int b = m / 2;  // m/2 can be replaced with any int in [0..m], e.g. a random value.
research(i, j, i, j + 1, b);
for (int d = 1; b + d <= m || b - d >= 0; ++d) {
  if (b + d <= m) research(i, j, i, j + 1, b + d);
  if (b - d >= 0) research(i, j, i, j + 1, b - d);
}
```

Here's the 2-billionth solution:

```
  78  56  28  29
  39  20  84  85
  28  34  61  18
  11  66  75  76
```

Comment: did you compute this with gpu cuda or kinda thing ? because it will take for ever on a normal computer for this code to yield results !

Comment: @user2548447 No. This code computes a 100 million solutions in about 3 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: what is your laptop specification ?

Comment: @user2548447 old Macbook Intel Core i7 2GHz.

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes interesting if we place condition that the matrix elements must be non-negative integers. Here's an O(mn) JAVA solution based on greedy algorithm.

```
int m=rowSum.length;
int n=colSum.length;
int mat[][] = new int[m][n];
        
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            int tmp=Math.min(rowSum[i],colSum[j]);
            mat[i][j]=tmp;
            rowSum[i]-=tmp;
            colSum[j]-=tmp;
        }
    }
        
    return mat;
```